# ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick can not be found

Tags: rocket.chat

I have got Rocket.Chat up and running on Plesk Onyx (ubuntu 16.04.3) using the docker system by running these commands.

```
docker run --name db -d mongo:3.0 --smallfiles

docker run --name rocketchat --link db -d rocket.chat
```

Everything is working accept the Avatar Resize which is giving and error:

> 'The image resize will not work because we can not detect ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed on your server.'

I have both installed on the server but for some reason it's not being detected by Rocket.Chat.

Am I missing something?

[image: Plesk Docker]

The other issue I get is when I go into the docker settings I have to change `Accounts_AvatarStorePath` to `ACCOUNTS_AVATARSOREPATH` and remove `Accounts_AvatarStorePath` otherwize I get an error about lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally.

There seems to be an issue with that image, so switched to the other offical image and now all working.